# Send Email To Recipient List Excel

Tags: vba, email, excel, excel-2007

I want to send an automatically from Excel as it is running reports, but I need it to do a VLOOKUP on the client name and select all email addresses that are assigned to that client. Can you help please?

So I will have a table such as below, on a sheet named `Client Emails`

```
 Company 1 | example@mail.com
 Company 1 | example2@mail.com
 Company 2 | somebody@somewhere.com
 Company 3 | you@here.com
 Company 1 | him@there.com
```

to make it easier to keep up to date. Right now I have the below code which sends the email correctly, but I would like it to pull the addresses from workbook and not the code as it is easier to update this way.

```
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
 With OutMail
    .To = "example@mail.com; example2@mail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .Body = "Hello World."
    .Attachments.Add ("Attachment")
    '.Display
    .Send
 End With
 On Error GoTo 0
 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: If you are sending to a company, how are you expecting to handle the possibly multiple email addresses? Are you going to use one for To: and then CC and/or BCC the rest? If you are only sending to one address then which one?

Comment: I will be sending `To` all the addresses under the business as we will only have a few addresses that client specifically requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a loop to look through the table of email address and concatenate the emails of matching companies into a string variable which you then use for the "to" section.

For example (inserted prior to your with statement):

```
Dim Lastrow as long
dim myemail as string
dim myrange as Range


'counts the number of rows in use
lastrow = Sheets("Client Emails").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each myrange In Sheets("Client Emails").Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

        If myrange = "Company1" then

            myEmail = myEmail & myrange.offset(0,1).value & ";"

        End if

       Next Myrange
```

You would replace "Company1" in the above to be the name of the company you were currently emailing.

The in your existing code replace:

```
.To = Email1, Email2,email3, .........
```

With

```
.To = myEmail
```

Comment: Thanks! I was getting a `Compile error:` that said `Next without For`. I added an `End If` to the line above `Next Myrange` and it worked!

Comment: Cheers have amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
company = cells(1,2)      ' Assign the source cell value of company name like VLOOKUP reference
a = 2
do while cells(a,1)<>""
if  company = cells(a,1) then tolist = cells(a,2)     'IF condition matches, To mail list will be assigned to tolist
a = a +1
loop

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
     With OutMail
    .To = tolist
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .Body = "Hello World."
    .Attachments.Add ("Attachment")
    '.Display
    .Send
 End With
 On Error GoTo 0
 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
```