# Send each row to unique email address in Excel

Tags: excel, email

I have an Excel sheet with the following contents/structure:

---

```
Email Address   | Subject | Email Body

user1@abc.com   | ABC XYZ | Information about

user2@abc.com   | XYZ XYZ | System code
```

---

I would like to send an email to: user1@abc.com  with the subject (ABC XYC) and the email body (Information about). Once done, it should move to the next line and do the same.

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912383/send-email-to-recipient-list-excel) and tried, but no joy

Some considerations. I think there should be a pause after, maybe 5 emails. Let us say 1 sec.  I could send up to 500 rows.

This is the code I tried:

```
Dim Lastrow as long
dim myemail as string
dim myrange as Range


'counts the number of rows in use
lastrow = Sheets("My Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each myrange In Sheets("Email Address").Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

        If myrange = "Subject" then

            myEmail = myEmail & myrange.offset(0,1).value & ";"

        End if

       Next Myrange
```

---

MY SOLUTION which is working.

```
> Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String,
> mail_body As String)
> 
> Dim olApp As Outlook.Application Set olApp =
> CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
> 
>     Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
>     Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
>     
>     olMail.To = what_address
>     olMail.Subject = subject_line
>     olMail.Body = mail_body
>     olMail.Send
> 
> End Sub Sub SendMassEmail()
> 
> row_number = 2
> 
> Do DoEvents
>     row_number = row_number + 1
>     Call SendEmail(Sheet6.Range("A" & row_number), Sheet6.Range("D" & row_number), Sheet6.Range("L" & row_number))
>         
>     Loop Until row_number = 102
> 
> End Sub
```

However, I would like to get the `Loop Until row_number = 102` to find the last row automatically.

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Comment: How do you want to send them? Outlook? Browser? Im pretty sure excel cant send them on its own :D

Comment: I added the code I tried. The first time, excel froze. Second time debug. I am trying that now.

Comment: @DirkReichel To be honest, I think I can do it through Outlook, I assume that would be the easiest. From what I understand from my research. Excel can use Outlook to send the emails.

Comment: Right now you are just lining up all subjects ... at least it looks like that and also is wrong :( Try something like: in your For ... Each loop `call MyOutlookMacro( myrange.value, myrange.offset(0,1).value, myrange.offset(0,2).value)` (delete the if ... then ... ) and write a macro in outlook with `Sub MyOutlookMacro(sSendTo as String, sSubject as String, sBody as String)`

Comment: @DirkReichel Thank you very much, I shall look into it for sure. I am still getting my head around it.